# AnyObject try cast to Equatable

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, equatable

I have an `Equatable` class

```
class Item: Equatable {
    var value: AnyObject?
    var title: String
    init(title: String, value: AnyObject?) {
        self.title = title
        self.value = value
    }
    //Equatable
    public static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return ((lhs.title == rhs.title) && (lhs.value === rhs.value))
    }  
}
```

But I want cast try var `value` to Equatable, So that get soft equatable result

```
if let lValue = lhs.value as? Equatable,   // Error
   let rValue = rhs.value as? Equatable {  // Error
    valueEq = (lValue == rValue)
} else {
    valueEq = (lhs.value === rhs.value)
}
```

> This code catch compilation error about Generic Equatable

How is I can do correct Equatable for this class?

**UPD**

I want use my `Item` in `UITableViewCell` in my storyboard. I Cant create generic `UITableViewCell`. And if I try do Item as `Generic<T: Equatable>` class, I will be forced to specify the types in my Cells,

```
var items: [Item<OnlyThisHashableClass>]
```

but I want use Item in Cells for any objects

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: you need to create a custom value type that conforms to Equatable.

Comment: Update your question with the exact and complete error message, not some summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy way - class stay NonGeneric, Generic only `init`, and in GenericInit create isEquals method

```
class FieldItem: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable {
    let value: Any?
    let title: String
    private let equals: (Any?) -> Bool
    init<Value: Equatable>(title: String, value: Value?) {
        func isEquals(_ other: Any?) -> Bool {
            if let l = value, let r = other {
                if let r = r as? Value {
                    return l == r
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        self.title = title
        self.value = value
        self.equals = isEquals
    }
    //CustomStringConvertible
    var description: String { get { return title } }
    //Equatable
    public static func ==(lhs: FieldItem, rhs: FieldItem) -> Bool {
        return ((lhs.title == rhs.title) && lhs.equals(rhs.value))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't cast `AnyObject` to an `Equatable`.

What you can do is define `Item` as a generic for which the `value`, `Wrapped`, must be `Equatable`:

```
class Item<Wrapped: Equatable> {
    var title: String
    var value: Wrapped

    init(title: String, value: Wrapped) {
        self.title = title
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension Item: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}
```

And, let's imagine that you have some class, `Foo`, that (a) isn't equatable; (b) is something you want to wrap in an `Item`; and (c) you really want to define them to be equatable on the basis of the identity operator, `===`. (I confess, I find that notion, which you call "soft equatable" fairly disturbing notion, but I won't go into that here.)

Anyway, you can just make your class `Foo` equatable on the basis of the identity operator:

```
extension Foo: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs === rhs
    }
}
```

Or, if you need to do this for many classes, you could even have a protocol for this identity-equality, and then your non-equatable classes could just conform to that:

```
protocol IdentityEquatable: class, Equatable { }

extension IdentityEquatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs === rhs
    }
}
```

Then any classes that you want to wrap in an `Item` that aren't `Equatable` could adopt this identity-equatable behavior with a single line of code each:

```
extension Foo: IdentityEquatable { }
extension Bar: IdentityEquatable { }
extension Baz: IdentityEquatable { }
```

---

As an aside, [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) has been approved and while not part of the language yet, offers the promise of Conditional Conformance in future Swift versions, namely:

```
class Item<Wrapped> {
    var title: String
    var value: Wrapped

    init(title: String, value: Wrapped) {
        self.title = title
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension Item: Equatable where Wrapped: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}
```

In this case, `Item` would be `Equatable` if and only if the `Wrapped` value was `Equatable`. This isn't part of the language yet, but looks like it will be in a future version. It is an elegant solution to this problem (though not, admittedly, your "soft equatable" idea).

Comment: but i use my `Item` in a many classes, for example in `UITableViewCell` in my storyboard. And if I try do `Item` as Generic class, I will be forced to specify the types in my Cells, but I want use Item in Cells as base class (value - AnyObject)